# Connect points to center in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am scattering points in a 3-dimension frame; do you how could it be possible to join each of these points by a segment (or vector) to the center (0,0,0) of the frame ?
Here is the code used:

```
from numpy import random
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d 

N = 10
coords = random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 1, size = (N, 3))

x = coords[:, 0]
y = coords[:, 1]
z = coords[:, 2]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d") 

ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, color = "green", s = 300)
```

And here is the plot obtained:

[image]

What I would like to get is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to iterate over each of your points, and use `plot3D` to draw a line from (0, 0, 0) to that point.

```
from numpy import random
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d 

N = 10
coords = random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 1, size = (N, 3))

x = coords[:, 0]
y = coords[:, 1]
z = coords[:, 2]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d") 

for xx, yy, zz in zip(x, y, z):
    ax.plot3D([0, xx], [0, yy], [0, zz], color = "blue")

ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, color = "green", s = 300)

plt.show()
```

[image]